# HTML/CSS - Joining multiple text elements together

Tags: html, css, alignment, text-alignment

I have the following code:

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">

  <p>Example text</p>
  <p>Example text 2</p>

  <div class="markdown">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <strong>consectetur</strong> adipiscing elit. Curabitur aliquam velit nec molestie pharetra. Etiam fermentum <code>ligula</code> non justo ornare mollis. Praesent vitae metus erat. Morbi vitae sollicitudin justo.</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
}
```

It has a wrapper div, a few `p` elements, and then a `div` with rendered markdown. However, as seen in the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7gxu0yoc), the first two `p` elements are joined together, but the rest of the text isn't. How can I get it to look like one continuous text element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `div` is being wrapped on the next line because it is enought big to do so. `flex-wrap` is responsible for this behavior. Without `flex-wrap` it looks like this:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

  <p>Example text</p>
  <p>Example text 2</p>

  <div class="markdown">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <strong>consectetur</strong> adipiscing elit. Curabitur aliquam velit nec molestie pharetra. Etiam fermentum <code>ligula</code> non justo ornare mollis. Praesent vitae metus erat. Morbi vitae sollicitudin justo.</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

However, it will only create 3 blocks side by side and will not look like a continuous text element. None of the flex properties can do this unless it's really a continuous text.

---

### Continuous text over block elements

You can use `display:contents;` to achieve something like this:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.wrapper * {
  display: contents;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

  <p>Example text</p>
  <p>Example text 2</p>

  <div class="markdown">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <strong>consectetur</strong> adipiscing elit. Curabitur aliquam velit nec molestie pharetra. Etiam fermentum <code>ligula</code> non justo ornare mollis. Praesent vitae metus erat. Morbi vitae sollicitudin justo.</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

> `display: contents` causes an element's children to appear as if they were direct children of the element's parent, ignoring the element itself.
>
> Source: [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/css-display-contents)

Comment: Thanks, didn't know `display: contents` was a thing

Comment: @APixelVisuals Yea it is pretty new. Just be careful because it doesn't work on IE11. You can check [supported browsers on caniuse](https://caniuse.com/css-display-contents).

Answer (score 0):

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  felx-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
}

.wrapper>p{
  flex: 1 1 0px;
  background: #ff88ff;
}

.wrapper>.markdown {
  flex: 1 1 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

  <p>Example text</p>
  <p>Example text 2</p>

  <div class="markdown">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <strong>consectetur</strong> adipiscing elit. Curabitur aliquam velit nec molestie pharetra. Etiam fermentum <code>ligula</code> non justo ornare mollis. Praesent vitae metus erat. Morbi vitae sollicitudin justo.</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Is this what you want ?

Yes --> use flex properties to put a width on display:flex children; you can also use width but I prefer flex

Moreover, if you use flex-wrap with an element which doesn't have a width or flex properties, then it will be wrapped if it higher than parent element